# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Double' type to the 'System.Single' type is not valid. Can I solve this error

Tags: c#

I have a DTO class in my project. So, when I run in run time I have this message:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Double' type to the
>   'System.Single' type is not valid.

This message appear when I put float or double type only. I mapped my DTO class, but the error continue. With decimal or int work fine. This is my DTO class:

```
public class LiberacaoItensDTO
    {
        public LiberacaoItensDTO()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(d => d.DataLib, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDateTime(DataLib)));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Juros, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Juros.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Desconto, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Desconto.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Acrescimo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Acrescimo.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, Liberacao>()
               .ForMember(d => d.Vencimento, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDateTime(Vencimento)));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Entrada, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Entrada.ToString("C2")));

                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, ItensLib>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Qtde, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Qtde.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, ItensLib>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Unitario, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Unitario.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, ItensLib>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Custo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Custo.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, ItensLib>()
                .ForMember(d => d.CustoDiario, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => CustoDiario.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, ItensLib>()
                .ForMember(d => d.UltCondicao, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => UltCondicao.ToString("C2")));
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoItensDTO, ItensLib>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Total, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Total.ToString("C2")));
            });
        }
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float DataLib { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Juros { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Desconto { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Vencimento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Entrada { get; set; }
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        public int IdProduto { get; set; }
        public string Produto { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Qtde { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Unitario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Custo { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float UltCondicao { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Total { get; set; }
    }
```

below my method. This method return a DTO object type:

```
public List<LiberacaoItensDTO> getAutoriza(int idorcamento)
        {

            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        //.Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                        .Join(contexto.ItensLibs, lib => lib.IdOrcamento, itens => itens.IdOrcamento, (lib,itens) => new { lib, itens})
                        .Where(a => a.lib.IdOrcamento == a.itens.IdOrcamento && a.lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                        .Select(libera => new LiberacaoItensDTO
                        {
                            TipoVenda = libera.lib.TipoVenda,
                            IdOrcamento = libera.lib.IdOrcamento,
                            Juros = libera.lib.Juros != 0 ? libera.lib.Juros : 0,
                            //Entrada = libera.lib.Entrada != 0 ? libera.lib.Entrada : 0,
                            //Acrescimo = libera.lib.Acrescimo != 0 ? libera.lib.Acrescimo : 0,
                            //Desconto = libera.lib.Desconto != 0 ? libera.lib.Desconto : 0,
                            Mensagem = libera.lib.Mensagem,
                            //DataLib = libera.lib.DataLib != 0 ? libera.lib.DataLib : 0,
                            Qtde = libera.itens.Qtde != 0 ? libera.itens.Qtde : 0,
                            Vendedor = libera.lib.Vendedor,
                            Cliente = libera.lib.Cliente,
                            Filial = libera.lib.Filial
                        }).ToList();
            return lista;
        }
```

And my rest service:

```
public class LiberacaoController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<LiberacaoItensDTO> getLiberacao()
        {
            return liberacao.getAutoriza(1000012093).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
    }
```

If I comment this line `Juros = libera.lib.Juros != 0 ? libera.lib.Juros : 0,` or other with float field, work fine. Otherwise not.

Comment: You realize that `Juros = libera.lib.Juros != 0 ? libera.lib.Juros : 0` is the same thing as `Juros = libera.lib.Juros`? I think the error here is that `0` literal is a `double`. If you have to do it your way(which I doubt) the line should read `Juros = libera.lib.Juros != 0.0f ? libera.lib.Juros : 0.0f`

Comment: @JakubDąbek, this way do not work. Is possible be the Sql server? I'm gonna migration for another version, maybe solve or not.

Comment: Why? **You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.** What I did?

Answer (score 4):

If in your database side datatype contains float then take double in your code side to mapping.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error too ,and I have float fields in the class(like your DTO class)

```
public class ReportArchiveHistoryQueryModel
{
    public DateTime ArchiveDate { get; set; }
    public float Energy { get; set; }
}
```

and I have sql table which contain float column.When I get some data via stored procedure ,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReportArchiveHistory]
     @SmartCounterId VARCHAR(10)
    ,@StartDate SMALLDATETIME
    ,@EndDate SMALLDATETIME

AS
    SELECT ArchiveDate,Energy FROM Archive
    WHERE Archive.SmartCounterId=@SmartCounterId
    AND Archive.ArchiveDate>=@StartDate
    AND Archive.ArchiveDate<=@EndDate
```

I got this error at `return result.ToList();`

```
 public List<ReportArchiveHistoryQueryModel> ArchiveHistory(short smartCounterId, DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate)
    {
        var pSmartCounterId = new SqlParameter("SmartCounterId",smartCounterId);
        var pStartDate = new SqlParameter("StartDate",startDate);
        var pEndDate = new SqlParameter("EndDate ", endDate);

        var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<ReportArchiveHistoryQueryModel>("exec dbo.sp_ReportArchiveHistory @SmartCounterId, @StartDate, @EndDate", pSmartCounterId, pStartDate, pEndDate);

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

**So I solved the problem as below:**

I think C# can't convert the data of float column to float field of class. Therefore I converted the float data which in the stored procedure to varchar.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ReportArchiveHistory]
     @SmartCounterId VARCHAR(10)
    ,@StartDate SMALLDATETIME
    ,@EndDate SMALLDATETIME

AS
    SELECT ArchiveDate,CONVERT(varchar(10), Energy )as Energy FROM Archive
    WHERE Archive.SmartCounterId=@SmartCounterId
    AND Archive.ArchiveDate>=@StartDate
    AND Archive.ArchiveDate<=@EndDate
```

After I changed the float field with string.

My query model:

```
 public class ReportArchiveHistoryQueryModel
{
    public DateTime ArchiveDate { get; set; }
    public string Energy { get; set; }
}
```

After when I need as float then I parsed again to float.

```
ReportArchiveHistoryBusinessModel reportArchiveHistoryBusinessModel=new ReportArchiveHistoryBusinessModel();
                    reportArchiveHistoryBusinessModel.ArchiveDate = item.ArchiveDate;
                    reportArchiveHistoryBusinessModel.Energy = float.Parse(item.Energy);
```

**OR second solution:**

just I changed float field to double  :)

```
 public class ReportArchiveHistoryQueryModel
{
    public DateTime ArchiveDate { get; set; }
    public double Energy { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved changed all float and double field to string in my DTO class and in my App I change to float and double again.